# How to search for users's first name and last name in mongoDB and returning the full object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to search for my users in DB using their first name and last name and then returning the full object of it but what I've found in another post is returning the `_id` and `name` which is concatenated `firstName` and `lastName`

This is the code I am using.

```
results = await StageOne.aggregate([
      { $project: { "name": { $concat: ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"] } } },
      { $match: { "name": { $regex: searchInput, $options: 'i' } } }
  ]).collation(
      { locale: 'en', strength: 2 }
  ).limit(limit).skip(offset);
```

And the response looks something like this

`{ _id: 5f064921a8900b73174f76a1, name: 'John Doe' }`

What I want to be returned is something like this

`{ _id: 5f08fc3b8f2719096146f767, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'johndoe@email.com' ... createdAt: 2020-07-10T23:39:39.310Z, updatedAt: 2020-07-10T23:39:39.310Z, __v: 0 }`

Which I can do it by running it like this separately for `firstName` or `lastName`

```
results = await StageOne.find({ firstName: { $regex: searchInput, $options: 'i' } }).collation(
        { locale: 'en', strength: 2 }
     ).limit(limit).skip(offset);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to add `$project` at the end of your pipeline.

```
{$project: {$firstName:1, $lastName:1, $email:1, $name:1}}
```

As In

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "name": {
        $concat: [
          "$firstName",
          " ",
          "$lastName"
        ]
      },
      firstName: 1,
      lastName: 1,
      data: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "name": {
        "$regex": "ohn",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      firstName: 1,
      lastName: 1,
      data: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d7OWILtmyIL)

You need to add part of your `first project` pipeline what are all the fields needs to be projected.

[Another way](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vyek-ev1ykt) to achieve this.

Comment: I am looking for something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/nEg9bi4ulAZ to return the full object that matches first and las

Comment: I am still not getting. Could you please explain what is the expected result?

Comment: Well as I said above I am looking for the full object not only the _id and a new argument name. So my actual object is containing _id, firstName, lastName, email, phone, avatar, status and more others. So once if I look for john doe or doe john, it should return me all the object that will match that first name and last name

Comment: @MarkusHayner But that's already happening in your play ground, Isn't. But you are expecting the same with your aggregate query?

Comment: Exactly, I have tried to use it as in the playground but its not return anything

Comment: [is it are you looking](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YdBbqNdwk8r) when you search for `ohn?` OR [this play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d7OWILtmyIL)

Comment: So I really need to put all the fields inside in order to be returned?

Comment: Yep, If you need to follow the same query, else I will provide you another option @MarkusHayner Is that ok for you?

Comment: This works but I thought would return the full object without specifying which arguments to return

Comment: @MarkusHayner Please check my edit - another option - with project, unfortunately you need to mention all.

Comment: the second options will work if I would have a search input separately for first name and last name first option is better